# Microsoft Word: Appendix headings level in Navigation pane

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I followed this [Microsoft guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-number-chapters-appendixes-and-pages-in-documents-that-contain-both-chapter-and-appendix-headings-in-word-2d9a939c-2863-45c3-bf5e-74b32972035d) to make a document structure with appendices to get this type of chapter and page numbering. The appendix headers are at outline level 7 as suggested in the guide.

As a result, in the `Navigation` pane the headers are nested within the last header of the document's main body. This hides the appendix headers when the navigation pane is collapsed (also in PDFs etc).

Is there a way to move the appendix headings to the top level, while maintaining the other functionalities of this way of numbering?

[image: Navigation pane]

Comment: That Guide was based on this article by Word MVP Shauna Kelly. http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html It originated prior to the invention of the Navigation Pane. It also predates simple saving to pdf with bookmarks. You can workaround the Navigation Pane problem by using a Table of Contents (not as convenient, I know). For the pdf, you are likely going to simply have to edit the bookmarks yourself manually.